# Normal bundles in complex vs differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Given a holomorphic vector bundle $E \to X$, let $E^{\mathbb{R}}$ be the corresponding real vector bundle, so that
$$\operatorname{rank}(E^{\mathbb{R}}) = 2 \operatorname{rank}(E).$$
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $Y$ a complex submanifold. Let $N_Y$ be the (holomorphic) normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$.
Is $N_Y^{\mathbb{R}}$ also the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$ viewed as real manifolds?

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the definition of the normal bundle as a quotient?

Comment: To spell out Michael's comment: consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow T_Y\rightarrow T_{X|Y}\rightarrow N_Y\rightarrow 0$ as an exact sequence of real bundles.

Comment: IIRC, the normal bundle of a holomorphic submanifold $Y \subset X$ usually does not appear as a holomorphic subbundle of $T_{X|Y}$, in contrast to the real situation. (That is, the exact sequence abx mentions usually does not split holomorphically.)